# Multiple async-shell-command commands in sequence

Tags: shell-command

What is the correct way to run multiple `async-shell-command` invocations serially?

For example, this will execute all at once.

```
(progn
  (async-shell-command "echo 1; sleep 1")
  (async-shell-command "echo 2; sleep 1")
  (async-shell-command "echo 3; sleep 1"))
```

But I want each command to wait for the command before it to finish first. (Of course in this case you can just chain them together with bash and `&&`, but you might like to have different output buffers, etc.) And I don't want to make the user wait, which is why I don't use UI-blocking `shell-command` function.

The only way I've figured out how to do this is with sentinels and continuation passing, which is very ugly.

Comment: Probably `shell-command` is no solution for you since you do not want to make the user wait for the commands to finish. If so, please give a note about that. Do you mean by "continuation" to wait for the currently running shell command with a sentinel reacting on `finished\\|exited` and start the new shell there? That is one way to go. Probably `start-process` is better for that. You could also use the [`async` package](https://github.com/jwiegley/emacs-async) and fire up all `shell-command` commands synchronously in a separate Emacs with its help.

Comment: Here are links to a couple of examples of how to do this:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/23071492/2112489 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/42879986/2112489

Answer (score 1):

> The only way I've figured out how to do this is with sentinels and continuation passing, which is very ugly.

Here it is:

```el
(set-process-sentinel
 (start-process-shell-command "Shell" "*Output*" "echo 1; sleep 1")
 (lambda
   (_ _)
   (set-process-sentinel
    (start-process-shell-command "Shell" "*Output*" "echo 2; sleep 1")
    (lambda
      (_ _)
      (start-process-shell-command "Shell" "*Output*" "echo 3; sleep 1")))))
```

To create the above expression programmatically, you can write a macro, e.g.,

```el
(defmacro multiple-async-shell-commands (&rest commands)
  "Run COMMANDS in sequences, each runs asynchronously."
  (cl-labels ((aux (commands)
                   (pcase commands
                     (`(,command . ,rest)
                      `(set-process-sentinel
                        (start-process-shell-command
                         ,@(if (stringp command) `("Shell" "*Output*" ,command) command))
                        (lambda (_ _)
                          ,(aux rest)))))))
    (aux commands)))
```

then you can use

```el
(multiple-async-shell-commands "echo 1; sleep 1"
                               "echo 2; sleep 1"
                               "echo 3; sleep 1")
```

> you might like to have different output buffers

The `COMMANDS` can also be a list of argument of `start-process-shell-command`, so you can set the output buffer:

```el
(multiple-async-shell-commands ("sh" "*output-1*" "echo 1; sleep 1")
                               ("sh" "*output-2*" "echo 2; sleep 1")
                               ("sh" "*output-3*" "echo 3; sleep 1"))
```

Comment: In `(set-process-sentinel process (lambda (_proc event) ...))` you should check `event` for a match of `"\\`finished\\|exited\\|killed"`. Alternatively you can check `(process-status process)` for `'exit` in the sentinel. Background: The process might also receive other signals such as `stop` or `run`.

Comment: Example for other signals: `(let* ((bash-buf (get-buffer-create "*bash*"))
       (proc (start-process "bash" bash-buf "bash" "-c" "sleep 5; exit -1;")))
  (set-process-sentinel proc (lambda (proc event)
          (message "Proc: %S, Event: %S" proc event)))
  (stop-process proc)
  (sleep-for 2)
  (continue-process proc)
  (sleep-for 2)
  (kill-process proc))`. (You can play around with the signal generating functions.) Those signals can also be sent with `kill` from the outside of Emacs.

Comment: Hm, this doesn't work for me. I get garbage in my process buffers, they live in `fundamental-mode`, and they don't seem to track processes.

Comment: @MatthewPiziak The first code block is straightforward, does it work for you? (It should create buffer `*Output*` and insert `1\n2\n3\n\nProcess Shell finished\n` in the buffer) The rest is based on the first code block.

Comment: @xuchunyang Ah yes, this works for plain text. I don't suppose there is a way to restore ANSI code compatibility?

Comment: @xuchunyang I got some improved behavior by using `async-shell-command` instead of `start-process-shell-command`, getting the process with `get-buffer-process`, and using a `(memq (process-status process) '(exit signal))` in the continuation to ensure that each process finished before the next started.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `async-defun` and `await` from the [`emacs-async-await` package](https://github.com/chuntaro/emacs-async-await):

```
;; -*- lexical-binding: t -*-
;; line above goes at the top of your buffer

(async-defun wait-for()
  (await (shell-command-to-string "echo 1; sleep 1"))
  (await (shell-command-to-string "echo 2; sleep 1"))
  (await (shell-command-to-string "echo 3; sleep 1")))

(wait-for)
```

EDIT=fixed parentheses
EDIT2= added lexical binding

Comment: First of all I suspect that your parens don't match here. If I fix them I get `Assertion failed: lexical-binding` despite the fact that I have `(setq lexical-binding t)`.

Comment: Do mind to add `;; -*- lexical-binding: t -*-` at the top of your elisp file. I do think that the assert that pops up is off, but I'm not 100% sure

Comment: @MatthewPiziak What does `(setq lexical-binding t)` mean? It is almost certainly an error. `lexical-binding` is a buffer local variable therefore `setq`-ing it in the initialization does not make sense. In elisp files it must be set as [file variable in a comment on the first line](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Lexical-Binding.html#Using-Lexical-Binding).

Comment: Okay, I've done that and it runs now. But why do you have `shell-command-to-string` instead of `shell-command`? There's no way to see the output.

Comment: no particular reason. I just happen to use that function a lot and I wrote it without thinking

Comment: This just hangs for a while. It blocks the user thread too.

Comment: oh, you're right... I'll leave here for posterity unless someone opposes... it looks @xuchunyang's answer is the definite one